# How can I make git track a folder?

Tags: git

I started a new project, and for some reason git is ignoring a one specific folder:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /static/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

fatal: Could not switch to '/static/': No such file or directory
```

even though the directory is clearly there. Git is tracking nearly every other folder and file under the /static/assets folder, except this jquery folder.

I have no idea how to get this folder/file under version control. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that Git never stores any folders. It only stores *files*. Files may have long names, like `static/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`, that *your OS* insists on separating into folder-y and file-y parts, but to Git, this is just a file with a long name. Avoid leading slashes.

Answer (score 3):

You have a / at the beginning of your path, so it is looking outside the git directory, try this instead:

```
git check-ignore -v -- static/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```